# how can we make a python program continuously listen for audio

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to make a virtual assistant in python, and I want it to continuously listen for audio
I tried this:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = r.listen(source)
        text = ""
        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
        except:
            pass
    return text.lower()

while True:
    text += get_audio()
    print(text)
```

but I noticed that there are gaps in between so I need help to find a method via which the program is listening continuously without any gaps.

Comment: Your recognition service will have some delays because it is an external call. You can minimize the gap by running your audio capture/listening and online recognition call in separate threads.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I am unable to find a way to install vosk on Windows
how do i install it for windows 10

Comment: Write me on github, I'll help you to install